# NPC navigation to waypoints in Unity 3D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, navigation

So if I wanted multiple different NPCs to each go to their own set of waypoints, what would be a good way of achieving this?

I have a setup where I have 3 sets of tags, Waypoint1-1, Waypoint2-1, and Waypoint3-1, as well as a script that auto populates all three sets of waypoints.

But how would I specify what waypoint for each of possible three NPC to choose, and then get it to target the next waypoint automatically? I.E. NPC 1 sets Waypoint1-1 as a target, NPC 2 sets Waypoint2-1 as a target, and then I have them move there. Once arrived, they set Waypoint1-2 and Waypoint2-2 as a target respectively. I don't need them to pathfind per se, and I figured transform.lookat should work; I'm more concerned with them moving between waypoints as specified.

Answer (score 0):

From the way you have asked the question, I am assuming that NPC 1 is going to walk to waypoint 1, then move automatically to waypoint 2 and finally to waypoint 3. The NPC will then repeat this, effectively walking around on a triangular path.

You could do this buy creating a script, let's call it `NPCMovementScript` and attach it to each NPC.

Inside the script, you could have a list of waypoints and then invoke MoveTowards on the NPC object to move towards each waypoint, I have included an example in the following script:

```
public class NPCMovementScript : MonoBehaviour
{
  public float speed = 1.0f;
  public List<Transform> listOfWaypoints;
  private int currentIndexOfWaypoint;

  void Start()
  {
    currentIndexOfWaypoint = 0;
  }

  void Update()
  {
    if (Vector3.Distance(transform.position, listOfWaypoints[currentIndexOfWaypoint].position) < 0.001f)
    {
      currentIndexOfWaypoint++;

      if(currentIndexOfWaypoint == listOfWaypoints.Count - 1)
      {
        currentIndexOfWaypoint = 0;
      }
    }
    
    var step =  speed * Time.deltaTime;
    transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, listOfWaypoints[currentIndexOfWaypoint].position, step);
  }
}
```

You would have to populate the waypoint `List<Transform>` by dragging and dropping the waypoint objects in to the list, in the right order, inside the editor.

You may also want to incorporate your suggestion of using the `LookAt` method too.

Hope this helps.